# get confidence interval for mixed lm predictions

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels, mixed-models

In R with the help of `lmer`, `ggeffects`, `ggpredict`, you can easily generate a plot of predictions and their confidence interval after fitting a linear mixed model using the `plot_model()` function. Below is one of the results:

[image]

I'm trying to generate a similar result to R in Python. Python `statsmodels` do not return standard errors for predictions so I tried to hand calculate it from one of the formula I found online, but the results are completely different.  so far I have:

[image]

I'm sure that I followed the formula wrong since the formula is for single variable regression whereas my model contains many dependent variables, and I'm losing hope in finding a function within python packages that will get me the interval.

Where should I start? I would like to stick with statsmodels, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably give a link to the formula you found. The [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions) doesn't have explicit formulas, but it has simple R code that you should be able to translate to Python ...  (You should also show us the code you used, and ideally a [mcve] ...)

Comment: @BenBolker My apologies for not sharing the codes, but thank you for the resource! it was really helpful as I had not seen that document before. I translated the codes into Python and saw that the confidence interval is similar to R when the formula is simple but with many parameters, the results diverge by a lot, (the range is 2 for R and 20 for Python).

Comment: OK.  But we still can't help much more without a [mcve]